# python date unix 1 day is lost

Tags: python, date, unix-timestamp

I have an error in python, when extracting one day. I'm converting to unix and extracting one day, yet the 11th of march - is always missing, no matter how big the dataset. Could anyone tell me what might be the error ?

```
from time import localtime, mktime, strptime, strftime
day = str(20180313)
one_day = 86400
for i in range(1,5):
    print(day)
    previous_day_unix = int( mktime( strptime( day, "%Y%m%d")))-one_day
    day = strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime(int(previous_day_unix)))
    print(day)
```

Comment: Please add expected and current output. When i run this the output is '20180313, 20180312, 20180312, 20180311, 20180311, 20180310, 20180310, 20180309' but if that's correct ... i dunno.

Comment: sorry for that. It's strange that you have this output. It probably has to do with the timezone. Thanks for considering this question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daylight saving time 2018 began at 2:00 AM on March 11, 2018. Thus this day wasn't `86400` seconds.

As you can see subtracting `86400` seconds is not a good way to compute differences in days. In general, all date/time "math" operations are a little more complicated than simple multiplies and adds due to things like timezones, daylight savings, and leap years.

A better way is to use a library, such as the `datetime`, which handles all of these things for you:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
day = str(20180313)
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(day)
    previous_day = (datetime.strptime(day, "%Y%m%d") - timedelta(days=1))
    day = previous_day.strftime("%Y%m%d")
#20180313
#20180312
#20180311
#20180310
```

Comment: wow, you are right, totally forgot about the changes in time. Thank you pault !!!